# How to keep Tooltip open in WinUI3?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui-3

How can I force a tooltip to stay open or at least increase the duration in winui3?
Most examples I found are either for wpf or uwp and none of seems to work.

Comment: What's the behavior you want to get? The tooltip will forever show? Or it always shows when the mouse hovers over? Could you please be more specific about the behavior that you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no property that lets you keep the `ToolTip` visible for more than a short period of time in UWP or WinUI 3.

What you can do is to replace the `ToolTip` with a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) and control its visibility programmatically by setting the `IsOpen` property.